# Download website as a desktop application

Tags: javascript, html, web, desktop-application

When I'm on some websites (e.g. YouTube), On the address bar I see the icon of downloading this website as a desktop application. I would like to know **how this happens or how the website can be a desktop application that easy? What's the logic behind this?**
*P.S: I'm using Google Chrome.*

The icon that I'm talking about is here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a PWA, which stands for Progressive Web App. You can install them as an application just like others. [See MDN for more information.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps)